# SQLite return rank value python

Tags: sqlite, rank

I have a sqlite3 table containing students' marks for an assingment. Below is a sample data of the table

| Id | Name | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mark | 87 |
| 2 | John | 50 |
| 3 | Adam | 65 |
| 4 | Cindy | 68 |
| 5 | Ruth | 87 |

I would like to create a new column 'Rank', giving the students a rank according to marks scored.

These are 2 main criterias to follow:

1. If both students have the same marks, their rank would be the same
2. The total rank number would be the same as the total number of students. For example if there are two student with Rank 1, the next student below them would be Rank 3.

Below is a sample output of what i need

| Id | Name | Marks | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mark | 87 | 1 |
| 2 | John | 50 | 5 |
| 3 | Adam | 65 | 4 |
| 4 | Cindy | 68 | 3 |
| 5 | Ruth | 87 | 1 |

This is the code that i have at the moment

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('students.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('ALTER TABLE student_marks ADD Rank INTEGER')
conn.commit()
```

Comment: What version of the `sqlite3` NPM package are you using? And **exactly** what version of Sqlite3 does that include? (e.g. NPM's `sqlite3` is currently version 5.0.2 which includes Sqlite3  3.32.3 - which is currently outdated).

Comment: Is your `student_marks` table normalized or not? If it isn't normalized, then why isn't it? If it is normalized, then where and how is student name information stored?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a recent version of SQLite, then you should probably avoid the update and just use the `RANK()` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT Id, Name, Marks, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Marks DESC, Id) "Rank"
FROM student_marks
ORDER BY Id;
```

Comment: Personally I'd use `OVER (ORDER BY Marks DESC, Id ASC) AS "Rank"` for the window function, and `ORDER BY "Rank", Id` to ensure 100% consistent and deterministic ordering.